# What is the equivalent of Java's .length for arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, java

I'm new to C#, and I'm trying to convert this code from java into C#.

```
    static public double euclidean_2(double[] x, double[] y)
    {
        if (x.length != y.length) throw new RuntimeException("Arguments must have same number of dimensions.");

        double cumssq = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
            cumssq += (x[i] - y[i]) * (x[i] - y[i]);

        return cumssq;
    }
```

I know java uses .length but what is the equivalent in C# since I keep getting an error

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: The C# version is almost identical except that it's *.Length* (capital L)

Comment: there is no equivalent `RuntimeException(string)` constructor in C#

Answer (score 3):

In C# public members should be capitalized:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    cumssq += (x[i] - y[i]) * (x[i] - y[i]);
```

Comment: Well apart from `RuntimeException` should be changed to `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0):

For the arrays, you want the `Length` property.

Also the exception type should be changed.

I think that covers it.

Answer (score 0):

the `length` should be `Length`, since members that are public should be capitalized so your code in C# should be like this:

```
public static double euclidean_2(double[] x, double[] y){
    if (x.Length != y.Length){
        throw new Exception("Arguments must have same number of dimensions.");
    }
    double cumssq = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++){
        cumssq += (x[i] - y[i]) * (x[i] - y[i]);
    }
    return cumssq;
}
```

also take note of the keyword `Exception` instead of `Runtime Exception`